# Trying to pass variables using text boxes to table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I think I have gone wrong in my website. My aim is to pass through the variables located in a HTML Form to a local storage, which will be displayed as a table. I have coded everything that is required, but unfortunately the `#add` button will not register the functions that are linked to it in the JavaScript.

Now, It is strange because my other JavaScript functions are working as expected, and is the only thing that seems to be giving me any bother.

The entities I would like to pass through are

```
firstName
lastName
address
phoneNo
postCode
email
gender
```

I am asking for someone to overlook my work and help me solve what could be preventing this from going through.

The following is the code that I am using to create this website;

### HTML

contactForm.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/formType.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/contactForm.js"></script>
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>


    <h1>Add Contact to Book</h1>
    <p>Enter your Contact's details (first name, last name, address etc.)</p>
    <p>All details will be added to the table.</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="firstname"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" id="lastname"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" id="address"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone No.:</td><td><input type="number" id="phoneno"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Postcode:</td><td><input type="text" id="postcode"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email Address:</td><td><input type="email" id="emailaddress"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td><td><select name="gender" id="gender" onchange="getSelected(value)">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="add">Add Contact to Book</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

### JavaScript

contactForm.js

```
/*global Contact, contacts, event, loadList, saveList $*/
/*jslint browser:true */

var firstNameField, lastNameField, addressField, phoneNoField, postCodeField, emailField, genderField;

 var addContact = function (firstNField, lastNField, aDDField, phoneNField, postCField, eMField, gNDField) {
var c = new Contact(firstNField.value, lastNField.value, aDDField.value, phoneNField.value, postCField.value, eMField.value, gNDField.value);
contacts.push(c);
};

var clearUI = function () {
var white = '#fff';
firstNameField.value = "";
firstNameField.style.backgroundColor = white;
lastNameField.value = "";
lastNameField.style.backgroundColor = white;
addressField.value = "";
addressField.style.backgroundColor = white;
phoneNoField.value = "";
phoneNoField.style.backgroundColor = white;
postCodeField.value = "";
postCodeField.style.backgroundColor = white;
emailField.value = "";
emailField.style.backgroundColor = white;
genderField.value = "";
genderField.style.backgroundColor = white;
};

 var addNew = function () {
addContact(firstNameField, lastNameField, addressField, phoneNoField, postCodeField, emailField, genderField);
clearUI();
};

var updateExisiting = function (index) {
contacts[index].firstName = firstNameField.value;
contacts[index].lastName = lastNameField.value;
contacts[index].address = addressField.value;
contacts[index].phoneNo = phoneNoField.value;
contacts[index].postCode = postCodeField.value;
contacts[index].email = emailField.value;
contacts[index].gender = genderField.value;
clearUI();
};

var cancel = function () {
clearUI();    
};

var showContact = function (index) {
if (index > -1) {
    firstNameField.value = contacts[index].firstName;
    lastNameField.value = contacts[index].lastName;
    addressField.value = contacts[index].address;
    phoneNoField.value = contacts[index].phoneNo;
    postCodeField.value = contacts[index].postCode;
    emailField.value = contacts[index].email;
    genderField.value = contacts[index].gender;
}
};

function addOrUpdate() {
addNew();
saveList();
alert ("You have successfully updated your Contact Book. You may now add others if you wish, or you can return to the other options.");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
loadList();
firstNameField = $("#firstname")[0];
lastNameField = $("#lastname")[0];
addressField = $("#address")[0];
phoneNoField = $("#phoneno")[0];
postCodeField = $("#postcode")[0];
emailField = $("#email")[0];
genderField = $("#gender")[0];
$("#add").click(addOrUpdate);
$("#cancel").click(cancel);
});
```

contactType.js

```
 /*global localStorage, window */

 var twoDigit = function (n) {
var str = n.toString();
if (str.length < 2) {
    return '0' + str;
}
return str;
 };

var Contact = function (firstName, lastName, address, phoneNo, postCode, email, gender){
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.address = address;
this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
this.postCode = postCode;
this.email = email;
this.gender = gender;
this.deleted = false;
};

Contact.prototype.toString = function () {
var s = this.firstName + '\n' + this.lastName + '\n' + this.address + '\n' + this.phoneNo + '\n' + this.postCode + '\n' + this.email + '\n' + this.gender+ '\n' + this.deleted + '\n';
if (this.deleted) {
    s += "Delete\n\n";
} else {
    s += "Don't Delete\n\n";
}
return s;
};


function buttonField(text, index, clickhandler) {
var btn = "<button id=" + index + " onclick=" + clickhandler + "(" + index + ")" + ">" + text + "</button>";
return btn;
 }

function tableData(content) {
return "<td>" + content + "</td>";
 }

function tableRow(clickhandler, index, tdElements) {
var element, tr = "<tr onclick='" + clickhandler + "(" + index + ")'>";
for (element in tdElements) { 
    tr += tdElements[element];
}
tr += "</tr>"
return tr;
    }

function checkBox(index, clickhandler){
return "<input type = 'checkbox' onclick='" + clickhandler + "(" + index + ")'>";
}

Contact.prototype.tableRow = function (index) {
var tr, me, btnText;
me = this;
btnText = buttonField(this.postCode, index, "showPos");
tr = tableRow("selectContact", index, [tableData(this.firstName),
                                       tableData(this.lastName),
                                       tableData(this.address),
                                       tableData(this.phoneNo),
                                       tableData(btnText),
                                       tableData(this.gender),
                                       tableData(checkBox(index, "updateStatus"))]);
return tr;   
};

var contacts = [];

var addContact = function (firstNField, lastNField, aDDField, phoneNField, postCField, eMField, gNDField) {
var c = new Contact(firstNField.value, lastNField.value, aDDField.value, phoneNField.value, postCField.value, eMField.value, gNDField.value);
contacts.push(c);
};

var saveList = function () {
var conts = JSON.stringify(contacts);
if (conts !== "") {
    localStorage.contacts = conts;
} else {
    window.alert("The contact could not be saved to the list. Please try again later.")
}
};

var loadList = function () {
var conts = "", i, cont, proto;
if (localStorage.contacts !== undefined) {
    conts = localStorage.contacts;
    contacts = JSON.parse(conts);
    proto = new Contact();
    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i += 1) {
        cont = contacts[i];
        cont.__proto__ = proto;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Which button is giving you the problem, `#add` or `#cancel`, or another one? When you click it, do you get any errors in your JS console? Which handler in your code above do you expect to be called for the button you are referring to?

Comment: The add button is giving me problems. My javaScript on my other pages are fine, but for whatever reason its not recognising the add button on my HTML form.

Comment: Try validating the HTML, and make sure you don't have any duplicate `#add` ids. Also, try adding an `alert('hello');` at the start of your `addOrUpdate` handler to see if that is being called on click.

Comment: thanks, the alert prompt did not display when I tried the add button and there are no duplicates for "add".

Comment: Your email input ID is wrong, should be: <input type="email" id="email"/> after this fix i got alert, at least...

Comment: I don't know why, but when I tried it that didn't give me an alert.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/89w8v378/ - please check it here...

Comment: My method of input, Brackets, doesn't seem to like that its being called externally. I don't know if its because the JavaScript is internal in jsfiddle that its working properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "called externally", John? Brackets is a programmer's editor, and is not where the code should be run. The code should be run in a browser. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. However, the problem that I was having was actually relating to where the reference file for the jquery was. A school boy error as it were haha! How do I close the question, for I've received enough help for this?